# Why is Refresh Apex not working while Inline Edit in LWC datatable?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, datatable, lightning-components, refreshapex

Why is refresh Apex not working during Inline Edit? When I edit the record, even though the new value gets updated, but in the datatable the old value gets displayed. How can I fix this?

.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="slds-m-top_medium slds-m-bottom_x-large">
            <div class="slds-p-around_medium lgc-bg">
                <lightning-input type="text" label="Search box" placeholder="type here..." value={searchValue} onchange={searchKeyword}></lightning-input>
            </div>
            <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Search" title="Search" onclick={handleClick} class="slds-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
        </div>
        <div class='slds-m-around_medium'>
            <lightning-datatable
                    key-field='Id'
                   
                    data={records}
                    columns={columns}
                    hide-checkbox-column
                    draft-values={draftValues}
                    onsave={handleSave}>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

.js

```
export default class Sample extends LightningElement {
    records;
    error;
    draftValues = [];
    searchValue = '';

    searchKeyword(event){
        this.searchValue = event.target.value;
    }
   handleClick(){
        fetchAccounts({key: this.searchValue})
        .then(result => {
                this.records = result;
        })
        .catch( error=>{
            this.records = null;
        });
    } 

    async handleSave( event ) {

        const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
        const notifyChangeIds = updatedFields.map(row => { return { "recordId": row.Id } });

        await updateAccounts( { data: updatedFields } )
        .then( result => {

            console.log( JSON.stringify( 'Apex update result: ' + result ) );
        
            getRecordNotifyChange(notifyChangeIds);
           refreshApex( this.records).then( () => {
            this.draftValues = [];
            });       

        }).catch( error => {
            console.log( 'Error is ' + JSON.stringify( error ) );
        });

    }

}
```

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
 
    @AuraEnabled( cacheable = true )
    public static List< Account > fetchAccounts(String key) {
     
        return [ SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :key ];
         
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static string updateAccounts( Object data ) {
        
        List < Account > accsForUpdate = ( List < Opportunity > ) JSON.deserialize(
            JSON.serialize( data ),
            List < Account >.class
        );
        try {
            update accsForUpdate;
            return 'Success: Account(s) updated successfully';
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return 'The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage();
        }

    }
     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`refreshApex` refreshs Apex data provisioned via an Apex `@wire`, indeed the input parameter must be the whole object returned by an Apex `@wire`.
You're calling an apex method imperatively, so you cannot use `refreshApex`, instead you have to call the method again.
[Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching)

> **Refresh the Cache When Calling a Method Imperatively**
> To refresh stale Apex data, invoke the Apex method and then call `getRecordNotifyChange(recordIds)` to update the Lightning Data Service (LDS) cache. Lightning Data Service doesn’t manage data provisioned by imperative Apex calls.

You also don't need async/await in `handleSave` method.
To fix the issue just replace `refreshApex` with `handleClick`:

```js
handleSave(event) {

    const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
    const notifyChangeIds = updatedFields.map(row => { return { "recordId": row.Id } });

    updateAccounts( { data: updatedFields } )
    .then( result => {

        console.log( JSON.stringify( 'Apex update result: ' + result ) );
    
        getRecordNotifyChange(notifyChangeIds);
        this.handleClick();

    }).catch( error => {
        console.log( 'Error is ' + JSON.stringify( error ) );
    });

}
```

By the way, if you posted the whole code of the component, you don't need to refresh the Lightning Data Service cache calling `getRecordNotifyChange` in `handleSave` method, just calling the apex method again is enough.

Comment: The other point is that the imperatively called method should not be marked as cacheable since the data returned does not want to be cached.

Comment: Why leave the getRecordNotifyChange in place?

Comment: @PhilW As per the code posted in the question `getRecordNotifyChange` can be removed, but I don't know if the OP posted the whole component, nor where it's used, so I gave the benefit of doubt, even if I think it is not needed.

Comment: Fair, but worth mentioning in the answer itself.

Comment: @PhilW edited the answer

Comment: @RubenDG On saving the edit, still the old value is displayed.

Comment: @user275494 is the Apex method marked `cacheable=true`? If so, remove that or set it `false`.

Comment: @user275494 could you please edit the question adding the code of both `updateAccounts` and `fetchAccounts` methods? Please also disable `Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance` from Setup > Session Settings

Comment: @RubenDG Added the code of the Apex methods.

Comment: @user275494 please remove `cacheable = true` from `fetchAccounts` method and add a `console.log([...this.records])` in the then right after `this.records = result;`